# Can I find all XML nodes with a given attribute in a QDomDocument?

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I'm using Qt 4.7.4. In my program, each QDomNode in a QDomDocument will have a unique identifier attribute. Is there a simple way to locate all nodes (in this case, only a single node) with a given attribute?

Nothing that I have found suggests that this is possible, but I thought that I might as well ask.

I suppose that I could place the identifier in a child node of the original node, search for the identifier node, and then take its parent, but I would prefer to keep it in an attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to recursively scan the document tree to find the elements yourself.  For example, to find all elements with a given attribute name:

```
void findElementsWithAttribute(const QDomElement& elem, const QString& attr, QList<QDomElement> foundElements)
{
  if( elem.attributes().contains(attr) )
    foundElements.append(elem);

  QDomElement child = elem.firstChildElement();
  while( !child.isNull() ) {
    findElementsWithAttribute(child, attr, foundElements);
    child = child.nextSiblingElement();
  }
}

QList<QDomElement> foundElements;
QDomDocument doc;
// Load document
findElementsWithAttribute(doc.documentElement(), "myattribute", foundElements);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for a great answer. I have used it, but i believe that you have forgotten a & in the Qlist (to make it a reference) in your function definition. By changing it to "void findElementsWithAttribute(const QDomElement& elem, const QString& attr, QList<QDomElement>& foundElements)" this worked beautifully. Please correct me if i'm  mistaken